# Evaluating the indefinite integral $ \int \sqrt{\tan x} ~ \mathrm{d}{x}. $

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have been having extreme difficulties with this integral. I would appreciate any and all help.
$$
\int \sqrt{\tan x} ~ \mathrm{d}{x}.
$$

Comment: Have you tried $tan(x)=u^2$ ?

Comment: Yes. Using this substitution, I ended with the integral $\displaystyle \int\frac{2u}{u^4+1}\,du$, and I was unable to solve that.

Comment: Wait, nevermind. I got it. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @user155812: You should have obtained: $\int \frac{2u^2}{u^4+1}\mathrm{d} u$, after which you use partial fractions, via $(u^4+1) = (u^2+u\sqrt 2 +1)(u^2-u\sqrt 2 +1)$

Comment: I rolled back the previous edit of the title because the use of "primitive" to mean "indefinite integral" is not universally understood in the mathematical literature.  There was no reason to edit it given that the previous title was already unambiguously clear.

Comment: @heropup Reason : When one wants to open a new tab in the browser by right-clicking the title, those right clicks will not be overridden by the Mathjax context menu.

Comment: Then include other text in the title, rather than using terminology that may not be understood.

Comment: The funny part is that all the answers lead to different closed formulas.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

$$y=\int\sqrt{\tan x}\,\mathrm dx$$
$$g=\int\sqrt{\cot x}\,\mathrm dx$$

\begin{align} y+g&=\int\left(\sqrt{\tan x}+\sqrt{\cot x}\right)\,\mathrm dx 
\\&=\sqrt2\int\frac{\sin x+\cos x}{\sqrt{\sin2x}}\mathrm dx \\&
=\sqrt2\int\frac{(\sin x-\cos x)'}{\sqrt{1-(\sin x-\cos x)^2}}\,\mathrm dx\\&
=\sqrt2\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,\mathrm du \\&
=\sqrt2\sin^{-1}u \\&
=\sqrt2\sin^{-1}(\sin x-\cos x)\end{align}

\begin{align} y-g&=\int\left(\sqrt{\tan x}-\sqrt{\cot x}\right)\,\mathrm dx \\&
=\sqrt2\int\frac{\sin x-\cos x}{\sqrt{\sin2x}} \,\mathrm dx\\&
=-\sqrt2\int\frac{(\sin x+\cos x)'}{\sqrt{(\sin x+\cos x)^2-1}}\,\mathrm dx \\&
=-\sqrt2\int\frac{\mathrm ds}{\sqrt{s^2-1}} \\&
=-\sqrt2\cosh^{-1}(\sin x+\cos x) \end{align}
\begin{align}y&=\frac{(y-g)+(y+g)}2 \\&=
\frac{\sqrt2}2(\sin^{-1}(\sin x-\cos x)-\cosh^{-1}(\sin x+\cos x)) + C\end{align}

Comment: Why?? In the integral $y-g$ You have the substitution $s=\sin x + \cos x$ and the expression $\dfrac{s'}{\sqrt{s^2-1}}dx$ becomes $\dfrac{ds}{\sqrt{s^2-1}}$. Can you explain that step??

Comment: @GabrielSandoval I think it's a typo, it should be just $ds$ instead of $s' ds$

Answer (score 44):

Let $I = \int\sqrt{\tan x}\;\mathrm{d}x$ and $J = \int\sqrt{\cot x}\;\mathrm{d}x$.

Now $$\begin{align}I + J 
&= \int\left(\sqrt{\tan x} + \sqrt{\cot x}\right) \;\mathrm{d}x \\
&= \sqrt{2} \int\frac{\sin x + \cos x}{\sqrt{\sin 2x}} \;\mathrm{d}x \\[5pt]
&= \sqrt{2} \int\frac{(\sin x - \cos x)'}{\sqrt{1-(\sin x - \cos x)^2}} \;\mathrm{d}x \\[5pt]
&= \sqrt{2} \sin^{-1}(\sin x - \cos x) + \mathbb{C_1} \tag{1} \\
\end{align}$$

and $$\begin{align}I - J
&= \int\left(\sqrt{\tan x} - \sqrt{\cot x}\right) \;\mathrm{d}x \\
&= \sqrt{2} \int\frac{(\sin x - \cos x)}{\sqrt{\sin 2x}} \;\mathrm{d}x \\
&= -\sqrt{2} \int\frac{(\sin x + \cos x)'}{\sqrt{(\sin x + \cos x)^2 - 1}} \;\mathrm{d}x \\
&= -\sqrt{2} \ln\left|(\sin x + \cos x) + \sqrt{(\sin x + \cos x)^2 - 1}\right| + \mathbb{C_2} \tag{2} \\
\end{align}$$

Now, adding $(1)$ and $(2)$:

$$I = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sin^{-1}(\sin x - \cos x) - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \ln\left|\sin x + \cos x + \sqrt{\sin 2x} \vphantom{x^{x^x}} \right| + \mathbb{C}$$

Comment: Wait, do you mean $\int(I+J) = \int (\sqrt{\tan x}+\sqrt{\cot x})dx$?

Comment: actually Here $\displaystyle I = \int\sqrt{\tan x}dx$ and $\displaystyle J = \int\sqrt{\cot x}dx$

Comment: It might be more elegant to write the solution as a parallel construct using $\text{arsinh}(\sin(x)+\cos(x))$, rather than the log equivalent.

Comment: @MarkViola not really, not everyone (for example highschool students)  is acquainted with hyperbolic functions

Answer (score 38):

Let $u = \sqrt{\tan x}$, then $u^2 = \tan x$. Thus $2u\;\mathrm{d}u = \sec^2 x\;\mathrm{d}x = (u^4 + 1)\mathrm{d}x$. Thus $\mathrm{d}x = \dfrac{2u\;\mathrm{d}u}{u^4 + 1}$. So:

$$\int\sqrt{\tan x}\;\mathrm{d}x = \int\frac{2u^2}{u^4+1}\;\mathrm{d}u$$
You can take it from here.

Answer (score 22):

As already mentioned in some answers, let $t^2=\tan x \implies 2tdt=\sec^2x dx\implies dx=\frac{2tdt}{t^4+1}$. Now, We can easily reach to the final answer as follows $$I=\int \frac{2t^2 dt}{t^4+1}=\int \frac{2 dt}{t^2+\frac{1}{t^2}}=\int \frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{t^2}\right)+\left(1-\frac{1}{t^2}\right) dt}{t^2+\frac{1}{t^2}}$$ $$=\int \frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{t^2}\right) dt}{t^2+\frac{1}{t^2}}+\int \frac{\left(1-\frac{1}{t^2}\right) dt}{t^2+\frac{1}{t^2}}=\int \frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{t^2}\right) dt}{\left(t-\frac{1}{t}\right)^2+2}+\int \frac{\left(1-\frac{1}{t^2}\right) dt}{\left(t+\frac{1}{t}\right)^2-2}$$ $$=\int \frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{t^2}\right) dt}{\left(t-\frac{1}{t}\right)^2+(\sqrt{2})^2}+\int \frac{\left(1-\frac{1}{t^2}\right) dt}{\left(t+\frac{1}{t}\right)^2-(\sqrt{2})^2}$$ $$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{t-\frac{1}{t}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\ln \left(\frac{\left(t+\frac{1}{t}\right)-\sqrt{2}}{\left(t+\frac{1}{t}\right)+\sqrt{2}}\right)+C$$ Now, substituting the value of $t$, we get $$I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\tan x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\tan x}}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{\tan x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\tan x}}-\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\tan x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\tan x}}+\sqrt{2}}\right)+C$$ $$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\tan x}-\sqrt{\cot x}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{\tan x}+\sqrt{\cot x}-\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\tan x}+\sqrt{\cot x}+\sqrt{2}}\right)+C$$ $$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin x-\cos x}{\sqrt{\sin 2x}}\right)+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\ln\left(\frac{\sin x+\cos x-\sqrt{\sin 2x}}{\sin x+\cos x+\sqrt{\sin 2x}}\right)+C$$

Answer (score 12):

A slight improvement: instead of $u^2=\tan\theta$, let $u^2=2\tan\theta$.  This gives
$$I=\frac1{\sqrt2}\int \frac{4u^2}{u^4+4}\,du
   =\frac1{\sqrt2}\int \frac{u}{u^2-2u+2}-\frac{u}{u^2+2u+2}\,du\ .$$
Observe that except for the constant out the front, no surds are involved.  Now substitute $v=u-1$ for the first bit and $v=u+1$ for the second bit.  You will need to be careful with the algebra, but it's not all that bad.

Answer (score 2):

> **Hint:**

Let $\sqrt{\tan x}=u$, $\quad \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\tan x}}\sec^2 x dx=du$, $\frac{1+u^4}{2u}\ dx=du$
$$\int \sqrt{\tan x}\ dx=\int u \frac{2u}{1+u^4}\ du=\int \frac{2u^2}{1+u^4}\ du$$
Now, make partial fractions $$\frac{2u^2}{1+u^4}=\frac{u^2}{(u^2+u\sqrt 2+1)(u^2-u\sqrt 2+1)}$$ Carry on to get the answer

Answer (score 2):

*Just another way to do it.*
$$I=\int\sqrt{\tan x}\,dx = \int\frac{2u^2}{u^4+1}\,du=\int \left(\frac{1}{u^2+a}+\frac{1}{u^2-a} \right)\,du$$ where $a=i$
$$I=\frac 1{\sqrt a}\left(\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{a}}\right)-\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{a}}\right)\right)=-\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\tan ^{-1}\left((-1)^{3/4} u\right)-\tanh ^{-1}\left((-1)^{3/4} u\right)\right)$$