# Integral of $\int \sin x\sqrt{\tan x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to integrate

> $$\int \sin x\sqrt{\tan x}dx$$

I put $\cos x=t^2$ but ended up with $(1-t^4)^{1/4}$. Can this integral be solved in terms of elementary functions?

Comment: Not in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: WA finding an anti-derivative expressed as a hypergeometric function is not a good sign...  It's also not comforting when we already see this for $ \ \int \ \sqrt{\tan x} \ \ dx \ $ :  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828640/evaluating-the-indefinite-integral-int-sqrt-tan-x-mathrmdx

Comment: the solution containes the elliptic function

Answer (score 3):

> *I put $\cos x=t^2,$ but ended up with $\Big(1-t^4\Big)^{1/4}$.*

We know that $~\displaystyle\int_0^1\sqrt[m]{1-t^n}~dt~=~\int_0^1\sqrt[n]{1-t^m}~dt~=~{a+b\choose a}^{-1}~=~{a+b\choose b}^{-1},~$ where

$a=\dfrac1m~$ and $~b=\dfrac1n~$ $($or viceversa, it doesn't matter, since the entire expression is completely

symmetrical$),~$ is the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) in disguise, as can be shown through a simple substitution.

Using the fact that $~\Gamma\bigg(\dfrac12\bigg)~=~\sqrt\pi~,~$ for $m=n=4$ we have $~\displaystyle\int_0^1\sqrt[4]{1-t^4}~dt~=~\dfrac{\Gamma^2\bigg(\dfrac14\bigg)}{8\sqrt\pi},~$

see [$\Gamma$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) for more information. However, if you are absolutely certain that the **indefinite**

integral is what you're really after, then your only two solutions are to either express it in terms

of [incomplete beta functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function), or to expand the integrand into its own [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series), and then

reverse the order of summation and integration, so as to obtain a [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).