# How do I calculate integral of $\int\frac{\text{d}x}{\sqrt{\tan(x)}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I'm having problems calculating this integral.

$$\int\frac{\text{d}x}{\sqrt{\tan(x)}}$$

I don't even know where to begin...

Thanks

Comment: Now the problem has become quite different. Is the tan in the radical or not?

Comment: From Wolfram: $$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\tan x}}=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}}\left(-2 \tan ^{-1}\left(1-\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\tan(x)}\right)+2 \tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\tan (x)}+1\right)-\log \left(\tan (x)-\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\tan (x)}+1\right)+\log \left(\tan (x)+\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\tan(x)}+1\right)\right)$$

Comment: The OP edited the question such that the denominator was $\sqrt{\tan(x)}$. I think this most recent edit has obfuscated the question's intentions.

Comment: yes, sorry. It is supposed to be $\sqrt{tan(x)}$

Comment: @teadawg1337 Yeah, sorry for that, there was a sqrt[2] and I interpreted it wrongly.

Comment: @Mc-Ac Apart from Lab's answer, if you u-sub $\sqrt{tanx}=t$ the integral becomes of the form $\frac{2}{t^4+1}$ and that integral has been worked out elsewhere on this website

Comment: Thanks! Will check it out.

Comment: This is effectively a duplicate of [THIS ANSWER](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828640/evaluating-the-indefinite-integral-int-sqrt-tan-x-mathrmdx) with the tangent function replaced with the cotangent function.

Answer (score 6):

HINT:

$$2\sqrt{\cot x}=\sqrt{\cot x}+\sqrt{\tan x}+\sqrt{\cot x}-\sqrt{\tan x}=\dfrac{\cos x+\sin x}{\sqrt{\cos x\sin x}}+\dfrac{\cos x-\sin x}{\sqrt{\cos x\sin x}}$$

As $\int(\cos x+\sin x)dx=\sin x-\cos x,$ choose $\sin x-\cos x=u$ for the first integral.

May I leave for you the second integral?

Comment: This is effectively a duplicate of [THIS ANSWER](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828640/evaluating-the-indefinite-integral-int-sqrt-tan-x-mathrmdx) with the tangent function replaced with the cotangent function.