# Error in my method of integrating $ \int_{0}^{\pi/4} \sqrt{\tan x}dx $?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, contest-math

I got this challenge question on brilliant.org: $\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\sqrt{\tan x} dx$

I first used, $\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\sqrt{\tan(\pi/4-x)} dx$ which simplifies: $\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\sqrt{\frac{1-\tan x}{1+\tan x}} dx$

Then, I used Weierstrass's substitution by using $t=\tan(\frac{x}{2})$ and $dx=\frac{2}{1+t^2}$ and simplified: $2\int_{0}^{\tan(\pi/8)}\frac{1-t}{(1+t)(1+t^2)} dx$

After some manipulation, I calculated the integral to be $I=2\ln(\tan(\frac{x}{2}))-\ln(1+t^2)+c$ and $I(\pi/4)-I(0)=0.53$

But Desmos tells something different:[image]

Have I done something wrong? I have rechecked a few times. But I find no error!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828640/evaluating-the-indefinite-integral-int-sqrt-tan-x-mathrmdx

Comment: What happened to the square root in the step where you expanded $\tan(\pi/4-x)$?

Comment: Where did you put the squaroot  after you change of variable?

Comment: @GuyFsone Do the algebra

Comment: @HansLundmark I edited. And I chose $t=tan(\frac{x}{2})$

Comment: @GuyFsone How is this a duplicate of that question ? That question is of no relevance to this question. This question is "Have I done something wrong?" that question is "Evaluating the indefinite integral ... ".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $x\mapsto \pi/4-x$ you get
$$
\int_0^{\pi/4}\sqrt{\tan x}\,dx
=
\int_0^{\pi/4}\sqrt{\tan(\pi/4-x)}\,dx
=
\int_0^{\pi/4}\sqrt{\frac{1-\tan x}{1+\tan x}}\,dx
$$
If $t=\tan(x/2)$, we have $\tan x=2t/(1-t^2)$, so
$$
\frac{1-\tan x}{1+\tan x}=
\frac{1-\dfrac{2t}{1-t^2}}{1+\dfrac{2t}{1-t^2}}=
\frac{1-2t-t^2}{1+2t-t^2}
$$
which bears no similarity with your computation.

Answer (score 0):

with $$t=\sqrt{\tan(x)}$$ we get $$2tdt=(1+\tan(x)^2)dx=(1+t^4)dx$$ thus
$$dx=\frac{2dt}{1+t^4}dt$$
not that $$\tan(x)'=\frac{1}{\cos(x)^2}=\frac{\sin(x)^2+\cos(x)^2}{\cos(x)^2}$$

Comment: I chose $t=tan(\frac{x}{2})$.