# Integration of $\int\sqrt{\tan\theta} \cdot d\theta$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Integration of $\int\sqrt{\tan\theta} \cdot d\theta$ is what.

I have tried to substitute $\tan\theta$ as $t$ but to no avail.

I do not know how to proceed. Please help.

Comment: This page should help: [Evaluating the indefinite integral $ \int \sqrt{\tan x} ~ \mathrm{d}{x}. $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828640/evaluating-the-indefinite-integral-int-sqrt-tan-x-mathrmdx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Define $t=\tan\theta$ and $u=\sqrt t$
$$\int\sqrt{\tan \theta}d\theta{=\int{\sqrt{\tan \theta}\over 1+\tan^2 \theta}(1+\tan^2 \theta)d\theta\\=\int{\sqrt t\over 1+t^2}dt\\=\int {2u^2\over 1+u^4}du\\}$$and expand $$1+u^4=(1-2\sqrt u+u^2)(1+2\sqrt u+u^2)$$